# Get XML node position

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have the following XML

```
    <cds>
        <record>
            <id>1</id>
            <artist>Rammstein</artist>
            <album>random</album>
            <trackNumbers>11</trackNumbers>
        </record>
        <record>
            <id>2</id>
            <artist>Rammstein</artist>
            <album>random</album>
            <trackNumbers>18</trackNumbers>
        </record>
   </cds>
```

I want to delete the record by the identifiier "ID" that I pass from another php file. So if I am not wrong I need the position of the record node to remove that node.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("books.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

unset($xml->record[x]); // x should be the id passed
```

Is this achievable? I've been trying to obtain this I am not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first select the `<record>` with `xpath()`, then delete it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$record = $xml->xpath("/cds/record[id='2']")[0];
```

This will store the first result (index = 0) of that xpath "query" in `$record`. It will be a record-node with id = 2. Note that PHP >= 5.4 is needed to do array dereferencing.

Now use unset:

```
unset($record[0]);
```

See the changes:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped me. Can you tell why did I get a downvote? :S